# Como fazer um programa baixar imagens de um site, pagina por página, utilizando id?

Tags: batch, wget

Preciso baixar várias imagens de um site, onde muda apenas o numero da página, mas o `id` da *tag* `img` é sempre o mesmo.

Gostaria de saber se tem como criar um programa que faça esse *download* e a troca de página, *automaticamente*.

O *id* é `#backgroundImg`. A pagina `?page=96`, por exemplo. Pode em qualquer linguagem ou meio.

Fiz esse código, mas ainda não consigo baixar.

```
D:\>FOR %A IN (1,1,96) DO
    wget -A.jpg  http://www.servidor.com.br/#/edition/T3916843A?page=%Asection=1
```

Estou usando `wget` no *prompt* de comando.

Comment: Qual é o problema que esse código apresenta?

Comment: Está criando um arquivo .html de 3kb e quando cria mais de um, fica assim: index.html.1; index.html.2...
Nenhum desses arquivos é realmente html.

Comment: não entendo porque "wget -A.jpg  http://www.servidor.com.br/#/edition/T3916843A?page=%Asection=1".. Obviamente não pegará imagem alguma assim.. Você pegou esse código de algum site? Não tinha nehum outro código a mais?

Comment: Não. Esse código eu mesmo que fiz. Porque é tão obvio que não pegará alguma imagem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sintaxe do laço [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) está incorreta, para declarar e usar um parâmetro do `for` é necessário prefixá-lo com `%%`. Também é necessário usar o [`/L`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) para que seja feito o `range`.

```pascal
FOR /l %%A in (1, 1, 96) DO (
  :: Aqui você usa o wget para baixar o arquivo
  ECHO http://www.servidor.com.br/#/edition/T3916843A?page=%%Asection=1
)
PAUSE
```

### Powershell

Uma alternativa em Powershell:

```
1..96 | % { $paginas  += @{ $_ = "http://www.servidor.com.br/#/edition/T3916843A?page=$_`section=1"} }
$webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient

foreach ($pagina in $paginas.getEnumerator()) {
   $webClient.DownloadFile($pagina.Value, "img$($pagina.Name)")
}
```

Comment: Ao tentar desse jeito, recebo a seguinte mensagem "%%A foi inesperado nesse momento".
Estou usando o cmd versão 6.3.9600

Comment: @RivaldoJunior Isso acontece ao executar o código da resposta? qual sistema você usa?

Comment: Essa resposta aparece ao dar enter no comando completo. Eu uso **windows 8.1**. Eu tentava para poder baixar uma apostila da faculdade, mas tenho como criar o _pdf_ com o _Google Chrome_, na opção de impressão da apostila, que o próprio sistema dá. A ideia era fazer um código que baixasse pelo o **ID** da tag **IMG**

Comment: @RivaldoJunior Postei uma alternativa em Powershell, crie um arquivo e coloque o código nele, salve o arquivo com a extensão `ps1`, depois execute ele pelo Windows Powershell.